# File uploaded to presigned URI, request response 200. But when using assetID for further API call - response 'Asset not found'. Adobe PDF services API

Tags: postman, export, adobe, export-to-word, adobe-pdfservices

Using Adobe '[PDF services API](https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/apis/)'

1. Generated AssetID and presigned URI using https://pdf-services-ue1.adobe.io/assets API.
   Got following as response.

```
{
    "uploadUri": "https://dcplatformstorageservice-prod-eu-west-1.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/16a9de6d208743239d1f694295f12626_254127B763EDC88B0A495FC7%40techacct.adobe.com/9fea6bbd-4f94-40d2-8463-d4e94aaa8424?X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDIBucznIV%2BQEMQw0PCLTAczK0ByJ4MmpHzLcmN3VNzE%2Fuhh2sH3Xw7009oBaypEOWod2yD%2FtfwLKFwS8Lq0sSmXyJFpd4vU67PaHAUdtxuJt4vXIaL9t%2FNFtTy66TZz4lTD4rRQQP%2BgJNO6C7f3JOlVeIyVTSyGieQ3jXSwkctCHmAA7YeWqKutr83tCUPeVzrPRyqNOx7BMA6vQUSpTelIVvY9F67s0IOYtuETwZeE0XFh%2BfKA%2FeN3rEdRGqqq60aUVNQTZZCnqInpFHQ8xu%2FcQM6fFPnUO79IVUC7fqpV4xMson7bHnwYyLThcwrmnyKJyCNvmZwl%2BNUbkpVMmY0lCcMMTtXYRtxxTV8yYq7zzcTWicI6XBA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230219T082707Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAWD2N7EVPJNDYTYLB%2F20230219%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=c291f06087e85b5221e2910aba53bf4ce40e12542e800c7f159f009d3bfa94c6",
    "assetID": "urn:aaid:AS:EW1:2ceb2ab0-e94b-4664-9bfa-0789e3fe111d"
}
```

2. Then uploaded PDF file to URI by making a PUT request with URI as the endpoint and uploading the file in binary in body. The response status of this request is 200 OK.
   [image: Uploading the input pdf file to presigned URI]
3. Then used the assetID for making a POST request 'https://pdf-services-ue1.adobe.io/operation/exportpdf'.
   [image: But this request gives error 404, 'Asset not found' as response.]

Can someone explain why 'asset not found', when PDF file successfully uploaded to presigned URI.

I tried to convert PDF to docx using adobe pdf services API, by making API calls using postman.
But got error 404 'Assset not found', despite pdf file being successfully uploaded to the presigned URI.

Comment: I believe you posted about this to our forums, and it ended up being another issue. RIght?

Comment: This was also the issue, got answer on the forum.

Comment: I was facing anther issue after this got resolved, was not able to generate jwt token using PyJWT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait some time for the file to uploads completely.

I have done this in postman, for now i can't done via my javascript code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).