# AssetID auto deleting somehow | Adobe PDF Services API

Tags: adobe, adobe-pdfservices, adobe-documentgeneration

**I'm having issue where my `assestID` of a file uploaded via the assets api, deletes/expires somehow?**

I'm using the Adobe pdf services api (https://pdf-services-ue1.adobe.io) to upload a `.docx` file to then perform the document generation.

At first the entire journey works perfectly fine - I can upload a `.docx`, retrieve its metadata, use the `assetID` of the uploaded `.docx` file to generate a `.pdf` by injecting `json` data, **however, after a day or two, the `assetID` somehow auto deletes and the document generation api returns `message: Asset Not Found.`**

The first time I thought it was a mistake on my end, the second and third time I was 100% sure I didn't action anything, the assetID just disappeared.

> **A few things to note:**
>
> - I'm on the free Tier. (Hoping this isn't the reason for the auto delete!)
> - I haven't tried deleting a document, so it couldn't have been a overlooked deletion mistake.
> - Documentation Ref I used: https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-services

If the free tier causes the assets to only live for a certain period, please point me to the documentation where this is noted - I must have missed that part if this is the case.

**Thanks in advance for the help!**

I also posted on the forum: [Link to post on the Adobe forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-services-api-discussions/uploaded-file-s-assetid-auto-deletes-after-a-day-or-two-is-this-intentional-on-the-free-tier/m-p/13965977#M6672)

> Ps. I'm aware of [this questions asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75498987/file-uploaded-to-presigned-uri-request-response-200-but-when-using-assetid-for), however, it's not the
> same as my journey works fine, it's only a day or two after where the assetID can no longer be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. The Asset endpoint is only for temporary storage when using the API. We tell folks 24 hours. So it's fine to use it more than once in a script, so for example, upload the asset and run N further API calls with it, but you should not expect it to last past the day.

It's not very well defined in the main docs, but the technical faq covers it: https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/faq/tech-support/#data-security--privacy-how-does-adobe-document-services-use-or-store-file-content